# Creating empty R dataframe and adding data row-by-row

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I'm new to R and this hurdle may be a case of me crossing my R and Python wires - I apologise if that's the case.

I have some data that is supplied as individual rows. I'd like to create an empty dataframe and add each row of data one at a time. I read several posts that recommend not doing this if possible but, in this case, I think it should be easier. I've read several posts giving solutions to the same problem and I think I've followed them. The code I have so far is:

```
# Create empty dataframe with 1 column for string and several integer columns:    
df = data.frame(name=character(), int_a=integer(), int_b=integer(), int_c=integer(), int_d=integer(), int_e=integer(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Create a series of lists containing the data
r1 = list(name="Row1", int_a=13234, int_b=567, int_c=566, int_d=53, int_e=11)
r2 = list(name="Row2", int_a=34454, int_b=34, int_c=643, int_d=33, int_e=56)
r3 = list(name="Row3", int_a=73857, int_b=3, int_c=226, int_d=4, int_e=55)
r4 = list(name="Row4", int_a=86754, int_b=346, int_c=384, int_d=35, int_e=59)
r5 = list(name="Row5", int_a=33748, int_b=456, int_c=461, int_d=6, int_e=85)
r6 = list(name="Row6", int_a=97865, int_b=34654, int_c=65, int_d=35, int_e=148)
r7 = list(name="Row7", int_a=36475, int_b=3444, int_c=365, int_d=55, int_e=34)
r8 = list(name="Row8", int_a=84748, int_b=454, int_c=345, int_d=148, int_e=884)
r9 = list(name="Row9", int_a=94848, int_b=23454, int_c=6548, int_d=7, int_e=566)

# Add row by row:
df = rbind(df, r1)
df = rbind(df, r2)
df = rbind(df, r3)
df = rbind(df, r4)
df = rbind(df, r5)
df = rbind(df, r6)
df = rbind(df, r7)
df = rbind(df, r8)
df = rbind(df, r9)
```

The end result is almost right but there are some errors – it looks like this:

```
   name int_a  int_b int_c int_d int_e
2  Row1 13234    567   566    53    11
21 <NA> 34454     34   643    33    56
3  <NA> 73857      3   226     4    55
4  <NA> 86754    346   384    35    59
5  <NA> 33748    456   461     6    85
6  <NA> 97865  34654    65    35   148
7  <NA> 36475   3444   365    55    34
8  <NA> 84748    454   345   148   884
9  <NA> 94848  23454  6548     7   566
```

And there a series of warnings is generated of the format:

```
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "Row2") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Can anyone explain why the strings are not being entered into the dataframe and why the row names are a bit odd?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to add rows one at a time? It's much safer and easier to create the data all at once.

Comment: Not to mention faster.

Comment: Agreed. Don't ever build a data frame row-by-row. You build data.frames a column at a time. Also don't have a bunch of variables with names like `r1`, `r2`, etc. Related objects should probably be in lists so they are easier to manage.

Comment: Thanks very much for the really rapid responses! The reason for wanting to add row-by-row is that the data I have is supplied on a subject-by-subject basis. e.g. (row1, 13234, 567, 566, 53, 11). Rather than trying to generate columns of data (with the inherent risk of skipping to the wrong column), it seemed more logical to add the data as supplied. But, if it's going to cause major headaches, it's probably not worth it.

Comment: Thanks flodel. Having an explanation is almost as satisfying as having a solution! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
options(stringsAsFactors = F)
your code ....
options(stringsAsFactors = T)
```

This will work.  Not sure why you can't just specify it in the data frame as the OP did.  Would appreciate clarification on this as well

Comment: Thanks very much for the post. That does, indeed, improve things considerably. The strings are entered correctly into the dataframe but the row labels are still 2,21,3,4,… rather than 1,2,3,4,… as I would have expected.

Comment: If you replace all your list() with data.frame() before rbind u'll be set.  Unfortunately I don't know enough to tell you why your problem occurs. e.g. r1 = data.frame ....